# Mysql fulltext short questions

Tags: php, mysql

If I want to search a mysql field for whole words only, and not use the LIKE syntax, I would use FULLTEXT.

But I don't know how it works really... I have noticed in PHPMyAdmin that I can set the indexes of fields to 'fulltext'... Is this what I am supposed to do?

And then use the 'match' syntax to search the words agains the 'search string' ?

Any simple tutorial would be great....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (including some examples) is located at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html